# Will certain types of beer get me more drunk more quickly?

Tags: inebriation

Assuming we're comparing equivalent amounts of alcohol, do certain beers get you inebriated more quickly or slowly? Does the amount of fizz make a difference?

Comment: [The topicality of this question is being discussed on meta](http://meta.beer.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-much-do-we-want-to-get-into-biology).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process of becoming drunk involves becoming dehydrated. So the higher the ABV, and less water you're taking on, the faster you'll feel the effects.

This is why shots get you drunk very quickly: there is little to no extra water in the mix. Other ingredients can add to this affect, and as I've personally noticed, some beers can produce very different "drunk experiences" than others - just like being drunk off wine, beer, shots, or mixed drinks can produce different results.

So, absolutely if you drank half a beer with twice the ABV while your friend drank 1 beer with half the ABV, you'd probably feel drunk faster than him. Assuming you're drinking at the same pace. Less water.

Comment: Actually it's the opposite way around.  Large watered down drinks enter the intestine almost immediately while small strong drinks stay in the stomach. It's the same amount of alcohol, but it gets absorbed much more quickly in the intestine. See [Alcohol concentration and carbonation of drinks: the effect on blood alcohol levels - PubMed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17720590/)

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, it depends on the ABV like any other alcoholic beverage. You can drink Natty-lights all night like college kids or you can get your hands on one of [these bad boys, at 67.5% abv.](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/10/24/worlds-strongest-beer-snake-venom_n_4157580.html#slide=2580657) I highly doubt carbonation has anything to do with it.

Personally, I prefer to drink beer for the taste, not to get drunk. So I'll experiment among many different craft brews.

---- edit ----

Started answering before I saw your edit. I'll keep this up for education's sake.

Comment: Yeah, I said 'equivalent quantities of alcohol', implying if you drink something with twice the ABV, you drink half as much.

Comment: didn't see that before, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Carbonation (fizziness) moves the alcohol to your bloodstream faster.  It's why in the USA, they will drink a shot and then chug a beer.  The fizziness in the beer makes you drunk faster.

Comment: Actually, that seems to be only somewhat true, and mostly a myth.  The most significant factor is how strong the drink is, but in the opposite way that one might think: diluted drinks enter the intestine sooner.  "*20/21 subjects absorbed the dilute alcohol at a faster rate than the concentrated alcohol. …14/21 subjects absorbed the alcohol with the carbonated mixer at a faster rate, with 7 subjects showing either no change or a decrease in rate.*" — [Alcohol concentration and carbonation of drinks: the effect on blood alcohol levels - PubMed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17720590/)

Comment: "*they will drink a shot and then chug a beer*".  The shot by itself would stay in the stomach for a while, where it will be slowly absorbed. The beer dilutes it and causes the stomach to release it to the small intestine where it is absorbed more quickly.